# Using VSCode SASS/SCSS compiler, my project will compile but the single file compile gives error with @import

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

On my Mac (OS 10.15.7 Catalina) using VSCode (1.63) SASS/SCSS Compiler extension, my project will compile correctly using my sassconfig.json file. However, if I try to compile a single file from the project using the icon at the top of my VSCode window ("Choose how to compile"), it gives the following error regardless of choice:

```
Can't find stylesheet to import.
1 │ @import "body";
  │         ^^^^^^
module.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

Here is a simple example of a partial .scss file called *_body.scss*:

```
.blue {
    color: blue
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

I create a test file with @import:

```
@import "body";
#item {
    display: none;
}
```

I then click on the icon and "Compile to Output". I get the above error. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Thats not much to go on. Is the file "body" in the same directory or another one?

Comment: Apologies - I oversimplified it. The file '_body.scss' is in the same directory as the test file and sassconfig.json - a directory called 'sass'. The project compiles flies to '../styles' successfully. In the test, I attempt to compile the single test file to 'Output'. If I choose any other option for compiling the test file, I get the same result. Thank you.